# Traveling with a cat on Lufthansa from Mumbai to Toronto

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, hand-luggage, lufthansa

I am very confused and any pointers or advise or notes will be of great help:

I am traveling with my 6 kilo cat on Lufthansa via Frankfurt, the concern is I have a soft sided bag which meets the 21x15x9 inches dimension but she also has one which is approximately 23x15x16 and hard shell.

Would they allow that in cabin?

Comment: Will you be taking both bags? Or only one of them?

Comment: I assume you have read [Importing or Travelling with Domestic Cats](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/animals/terrestrial-animals/imports/policies/live-animals/pets/cats/eng/1331904105485/1331904720313), and are planning on observing the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

See [Transporting animals as additional carry-on baggage in the cabin](https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/animals-as-additional-carry-on-baggage), especially "Specifications for the transport container":

"The maximum size is 55 x 40 x 23 cm (22 x 16 x 9 in).". The container has to go under the seat in front of you, so the dimensions really do matter. 23x15x16 is likely to be too tall to fit.